# Friendly order number - start sequence at specific number

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Folks:

I'm having trouble getting my head around friendly order numbers and sequencing. The client has asked for his sequence to start at 11 000.

I can set up a sequence that starts at 1 based on the docs. I can get this to show on the email receipt. What I'd like to know:

How can I get this to start at 11000 and be sure it rolls over to 12000 when orders hit that number?

I'm guessing that whatever the code winds up being, it's set in the "Order Reference Number Format" field, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have created the sequence (starting at 1) with your sequence key/id you can manually reset/update the number in the `craft_sequences` table in the `next` column. Obviously if you reset the number, you could get duplicate order reference numbers though if you are not careful.

Alternatively, you could just let the sequence start at `1` and use twig to add 11000 to the sequence number within the Order Reference Number Format.

Your Order Reference Number Format would look like this: `11000+seq('mySeqId')`